# Why I'm not able to open django app on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, pycharm

I'm trying to test out my app but uploading it to `Heroku` but when I try to open it the following error appears

I tried to `Heroku` restart but nothing changes.

I have already pushed it and made it live, is just when I try to open it

```
2019-08-05T10:28:35.985995+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-badlands-35223.herokuapp.com request_id=1a6f1655-5d02-43c7-b629-c2b4897e76bf fwd="83.174.32.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-08-05T10:28:36.411718+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-badlands-35223.herokuapp.com request_id=d4d9f0e0-8495-43e2-929b-8664f88503e7 fwd="83.174.32.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-08-05T10:29:31.130647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-badlands-35223.herokuapp.com request_id=2f3ab1c6-7b2f-47fd-827e-c4fc1725eda3 fwd="83.174.32.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-08-05T10:29:31.390998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-badlands-35223.herokuapp.com request_id=088bbe15-3618-48d9-8c59-3a0d88d170f1 fwd="83.174.32.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to format your error traces with proper code formatting (see [ask]) to make it easier for us to read. Now, this error stack does not give us any information, except that heroku returns a 503 error because your app crashes. You need to look at the logs of your app (have you setup [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/) to disk?) in order to understand why your app is crashing.

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: I added the link to the documentation in my comment. You'll find a simple [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#examples) of how to log to file.

Comment: ...except that's not the right way to log on *Heroku*. [Log to `stdout` or `stderr`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) ([not to a file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)) so log entries are included in the Heroku log stream. If you want you can also set up a [logging addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#logging) like Papertrail, or a custom [log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains).